# How can I influence in which margin the output of \marginnote gets printed?

Tags: double-sided, marginnote

Is there a way to specify the side of the margin note in a double-sided paper according to where `\marginnote` is called?

The following figure explains what I mean:

[image]

Here is my test code:

```
%% PNAStwoS.tex
%% Sample file to use for PNAS articles prepared in LaTeX
%% For two column PNAS articles
%% Version: Apr 15, 2008 


%% BASIC CLASS FILE
\documentclass{pnastwo}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}

%% ADDITIONAL OPTIONAL STYLE FILES
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pnastwoF}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0.1cm}

%% OPTIONAL MACRO DEFINITIONS
\def\s{\sigma}


%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% For PNAS Only:
\url{www.pnas.org/cgi/doi/10.1073/pnas.0709640104}
\copyrightyear{2008}
\issuedate{Issue Date}
\volume{Volume}
\issuenumber{Issue Number}
%\setcounter{page}{2687} %Set page number here if desired
%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\title{Almost sharp fronts for the surface geostrophic equation}

\author{xxxx\affil{1}{xxxx},
xxx\affil{2}{xxxn},
\and
xxx\affil{2}{}}

\contributor{xxx}

\maketitle

\begin{article}
\begin{abstract}
\marginnote{Note on the left} xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\end{abstract}

\keywords{monolayer | structure | x-ray reflectivity | molecular electronics}

\abbreviations{SAM, self-assembled monolayer; OTS,
octadecyltrichlorosilane}

\dropcap{I}n this article we study the evolution of ``almost-sharp'' fronts
for the surface quasi-geostrophic equation. This 2-D active scalar
equation reads for the surface quasi-geostrophic equation. 

\marginnote{Note on the right} end.

\end{article}

\end{document}
```

The result of such code is:

[image]

All notes are on the right. I need one of them to be on the left.

I have upload a smallest test and its required class files to: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45318932/mariginnotetest.zip

Comment: Using the `twoside` class option should do this, as in `\documentclass[twoside]{article}` (the `book` class uses `twoside` by default).

Comment: I am using a customized latex template. It is double-sided, but I do not need to put twoside on the \documentclass option. I tried to put [twoside] there. There seems to be no difference made. All notes are on the rigth hand sight.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Leo Relevant information is missing; can you add a minimal example of code and also a link for the customized class?

Comment: You don't need `twoside`, but `twocolumn`; but the `marginnote` package is not able to put notes on the nearest margin; it uses the outer margin for `twoside` and always the right margin for `oneside`. On the other hand, `\marginpar` fails with the `pnastwo` class. `:-(`

Comment: @egreg Still thank you for your efforts. :)

Comment: I'm inclined to think that the class purposely makes marginal notes illegal. It's quite peculiar in some of its aspects, for instance in the treatment of figures and tables that *must* be placed at the end.

Comment: I really really hate this class. Such a mass.... You can not change it though....